# Fill Hidden Fields with text from a text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have multiple form fields that are hidden fields that need to be filled in based on the email address.

For example:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="255" class="cat_textbox" id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" />
<!-- These fields are hidden -->
<input type="text" maxlength="255" class="cat_textbox" id="Username" name="Username" />
<input id="cc-email-fill" type="text" name="ea" size="20" value="">
<!-- End hidden fields -->
```

I tried the following code to fill the fields but it didn't work.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
  $j('#EmailAddress').change(function() {
    $j('#Username').val($(this).val());
    $j('#cc-email-fill').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

How do I fill the hidden fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use $ when jQuery was assigned to $j.

```
$j('#Username').val($(this).val());
$j('#cc-email-fill').val($(this).val());
```

Should be:

```
$j('#Username').val($j(this).val());
$j('#cc-email-fill').val($j(this).val());
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot! I hate it when I miss the little things. Thanks